# Unable to add tracks to a playlist after getting playlist tracks

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm working on a program that checks if a song is already in a playlist, and then it will add the song if it is not in the playlist.

I am able to get all of the track IDs from the playlist, but then I am unable to add a new song to the playlist.

---

This is the code I use to get the playlist track IDs, which works without any issues:

```
def get_playlist_tracks(username_gpt, playlist_id_gpt, sp_gpt):
    track_ids = []
    try:
        results_gpt = sp_gpt.user_playlist_tracks(username_gpt, playlist_id_gpt)
        tracks = results_gpt['items']
        while results_gpt['next']:
            results_gpt = sp_gpt.next(results_gpt)
            tracks.extend(results_gpt['items'])

        for x in range(len(tracks)):
            track_ids.append(tracks[x]['track']['id'])

    except Exception as e_gpt:
        print(e_gpt)

    return track_ids
```

This is the code that is supposed to add a new track to the playlist, if the track ID isn't already in the playlist:

```
if not TrackInPlaylist:
    try:
        sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, track_id)
        track_IDs.append(track_id[0])
        print("Track Added to Playlist!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("failed add")
```

The error I get when trying to add a track is this:

```
"error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
}
```

If I don't use the `get_playlist_tracks()` function, then I am able to add songs to the playlist without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but looks like the problem is the type of authorization you need to perform this, you will need to get an oauth2 access token with scopes as:
user-read-private
user-read-email
playlist-read-private
playlist-modify-public
playlist-modify-private
as explained in here https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/
and pass the access token in the call to add the track